# Significance of depth level (in a closure table) and how to get it done in php

Tags: php, sql, database

Studying about the closure table I came across an example which has a column named “depth” which represents the depth level from the root to the tree.

```
comment_closure
- ancestor
- descendant
- depth
```

Tutorial:

https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql

What I do not understand is-

1. The need for having a depth column?
2. and if it is significant how do I code this on at the programming (php) level, since the database wouldn’t be visible on the front end for me decide what level the descendant is at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I have not often had a Depth column in such a table. Conclusion: you do not need it for your code to function.
While looping over elements and going deeper in the structure you can keep track of the depth yourself. Or if you start somewhere halfway the structure, you could query up the tree to find out the depth.

That said, looking at it from a convenience and performance perspective, it would be good to always have the depth column:

- During setup of the tree you always know (or can find out) the depth.
- After that the depth will not change (unless the structure changes at some point in time, in which case you have to change the depths of all items as well ofcourse)
- Doing it at setup-time instead of while reading it will be much more efficiënt and optimize readability as well, since you don't have to lookup things you already know.

Now why would you need the depth? That totally depends on your use case.
Like I said, I almost never have had a depth-column because I don't need it.

But I could think of use-cases where depth can be convenient, e.g.:

- all items with depth 3 are of a certain type. So you can map the depth to a type or class;
- or in a menu structure for instance you could have all items with a certain depth a certain CSS style
- maybe in a certain case you only want to query all items with depth 1

I hope this answers your question.